# insert into database, then send email

Tags: php

I'm forced to use PHP against my will, so I'll need some help with this.

After googling, I have the following basic code and am wondering whether it is OK.

This is for a pre-launch "coming soon" page, where user enter an email address, which gets inserted into a mysql database and gets a reply message. This is all happening on a hosted server.

Ideally, I want to generate some HTML with images etc and send that HTML in the email body. Does someone have any idea how to do that in PHP?

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost:3306";
    $username = "userblah";
    $password = "passblah";
    $dbname = "blah";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO prelaunch_users (email)
    VALUES ($_GET['email'];)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

    $to      = $_GET['email'];
    $subject = 'Welcome';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: blah@blah.co.nz' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: blah@blah.co.nz' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I think I'd need a username and password for the hosted mail server there probably as well.

Thank you

Paul

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: Use prepared statements for MySQL queries. This way you'll be safe against most common SQL injection attacks.

Comment: So what's your problem? data not inserting or mail not going?

Comment: Just wanted some input on how good that code is and any corrections needed. And also how to create an email template and send it as the $message parameter. I'm googling the latter as we speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prpared statment like below:-

```
<?php
    if(!empty(trim($_GET['email']))){
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "userblah", "passblah", "blah");

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO prelaunch_users (email) VALUES (?)")) {

            $stmt->bind_param("s",$_GET['email']);

            if($stmt->execute()){
               // Add you mail code here
            }else{
                 echo "Error: ". $conn->error;
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }
        $conn->close();
    }else{
        die('email is required');
    }
?>
```

And for sending html mail with image. Please check below thread

[Sending HTML Email With Images - PHP Tutorial](http://phpform.net/html_mail.php)

Comment: user460114  glad to help you